# Search by specific characters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I am trying to make a search in the base of the corresponding symbols for the fields I need, the maximum that I could do

```
find({ carstvo:  "Большое"  })
```

[image]

as you can see I only get the exact value from the field.

I need to enter certain characters and get those elements that correspond to those characters and in those fields that I specified case-insensitively.

For example:

[image]

I think this is a very simple task, but for some reason I could not find a solution on the Internet, I tried in the aggregations tab, but could not find a solution, please tell me.

```
{"carstvo": {$regex: 'Боль', $options: "i"}, "znatnoe": {$regex: 'Боль', $options: "i"}}
```

why this don't work ???????

Comment: both match are in different documents, and your query doing $and match, you need to specify $or like this `$or: [ { "carstvo": { $regex: "Боль", $options: "i" }, },{ "znatnoe": { $regex: "Боль", $options: "i" } } ]`

Comment: Or use text search.

Comment: please tell me how to use text

Answer (score 0):

```
$or: [ { "carstvo": { $regex: "Боль", $options: "i" }, },{ "znatnoe": { $regex: "Боль", $options: "i" } } ]
```

this is my decision, but I'm sure there is better, because I will have to create a variable to insert it for each field